# How to Update State of class component from functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, react-hooks

Am Using pagination in my project here pagination component is a functional one am trying to update the currentPage which is state of view statement component.when i debug the code in the initial render i get props as undefined & if i click next the state is not updated immediately it calls the props.tableRow() and then again comes back to pagination updates the state before this details get mapped.
need some solution thanks in advance

```
import React ,{useState} from 'react'
import { Card, InputGroup, FormControl, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

 function Pagination(props) {
     debugger
     const intialstate = props.currentPage
     const [currentPage, setcurrentPage] = useState(intialstate);
    // const lastIndex = props.currentPage * props.detailsperpage;
    // const firstIndex = lastIndex - props.detailsperpage;
    // const currentDetails = props.details.slice(firstIndex,lastIndex);
    const totalpages = props.details.length / props.detailsperpage;

    const pageNumcss = {
       width :"45px",
       border : "1px solid #17A2BB",
       color:"#17A2BB",
       textAlign: "center", 
       fontWeight : "bold"
    }

 const changePage = event => {
    if (event.target.name === null) {
        setcurrentPage({
        currentPage : 1
      })
    }
    setcurrentPage({
     [event.target.name] : event.target.value
    });
  };

  const firstPage = () =>{
    if (props.currentPage > 1) {
      setcurrentPage({
        currentPage : 1
      })
      props.tabRow({currentPage : currentPage })
    }

  };
  const prevPage = () =>{
    if (props.currentPage > 1) {
     setcurrentPage(prevCurrentpage =>({
       currentPage : prevCurrentpage - 1
     }));     
     props.tabRow({currentPage : currentPage})
    }
 };

 const nextPage = () =>{  
     debugger
   let condition = Math.ceil(props.details.length/props.detailsperpage)
   if (props.currentPage < condition) {
     setcurrentPage( prevCurrentpage => ({   
       currentPage : prevCurrentpage + 1
     }));   
     props.tabRow({currentPage : currentPage })
    }
 };

 const lastPage = () =>{
   let condition = Math.ceil(props.details.length/props.detailsperpage)
   if (props.currentPage < condition) {
     setcurrentPage({
       currentPage : condition
     })     
     props.tabRow(currentPage)
    }

 };

    return (
        <div>
             <Card.Footer >
            <div style={{float:"left"}}>
             showing page {props.currentPage} of {totalpages}
            </div>
            <div style={{float:"right"}}>
              <InputGroup size="sm">
              <InputGroup.Prepend>
                 <Button type="button" variant="outline-info" disabled={props.currentPage === 1 ? true : false} onClick={firstPage}>
                   First
                 </Button>
                 <Button type="button" variant="outline-info" disabled={props.currentPage === 1 ? true : false} onClick={prevPage}>
                   Prev
                 </Button>
              </InputGroup.Prepend>
              <FormControl disabled style={pageNumcss} name="currentPage" value={props.currentPage} onChange={changePage}/>
              <InputGroup.Append>
                 <Button type="button" variant="outline-info" disabled={props.currentPage === totalpages ? true : false} onClick={nextPage}>
                   Next
                 </Button>
                 <Button type="button" variant="outline-info" disabled={props.currentPage === totalpages ? true : false} onClick={lastPage}>
                   Last
                 </Button>
              </InputGroup.Append>
              </InputGroup>
          </div>
          </Card.Footer>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Pagination
```

my view statement code here
i also set the currentPage state as 1 for the initial render of details

```
  tabRow = (currentPage) => { 
      debugger
      const lastIndex = this.state.currentPage * this.state.detailsperpage;
      const firstIndex =  lastIndex - this.state.detailsperpage;
      const currentDetails = this.state.details.slice(firstIndex,lastIndex); 
      console.log(this.state.currentPage,"state")
      console.log(currentPage,"prop");
      return currentDetails.map(function(object, i){ 
          return <Table obj={object} key={i} />;    
      });   
    }  
    <Pagination currentPage={currentPage} detailsperpage={detailsperpage} details={details} tabRow={this.tabRow}  ></Pagination>
```

Comment: Can you please host it somewhere it is runnable. Preferrably codesandbox. I would have extracted whole logic into custom hook so that it can be reused. I have worked on something similar and here is first draft [demo](https://gautamits.github.io/React-Pagination/). Please see if it works for you.

Comment: @gautamits check this https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-butterfly-6v1lo?file=/src/ViewStatement.js

Comment: There doesnt seems to be an issue with react. Your algorithm is rendering buttons disabled. Please check your logic. Here is working [pagination](https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bartik-uj505?file=/src/Pagination.js) component.

Comment: @gautamits nope still its the same applied all the changes you did, but in your case its working fine i mean the codesandbox.

Comment: I removed disabled attributes from all form components and it started working fine.

Comment: tried that too the state is not setting immediately in the pagination component,i checked it while debugging like first it goes to the onclick method nothing changes it goes to Tablerow method in viewstatement (with prev state) and then again it comes to the onclick function changes the state. this is my code flow while debugging.