# How to get data from JSON ReactJs

Tags: json, reactjs, chart.js

I have a JSON data like this:
[My JSON data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6CP7.png)

And this is my code:

```js
class WorldLineChart extends Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.state = {
          data: []
        };
      }
    componentDidMount(){
        axios.get(`https://td.fpt.ai/corona/corona-total.json`)
        .then(res => {
            const data = res.data;
            console.log(data);
            this.setState({data: data});
        });
    }

    render(){

        const data = this.state
       
        return(
            <div>
               
            </div>
        )
    }

}
```

This is what i get after running above code:
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzSj1.png)

I wonder how can i get all the key and each values(which is an array) to draw an line chart using ReactJs.

This is my linechart's code:

```js
const lineChart = (
        data
        ? (
            <Line
                data = {{
                    labels: //what i have to put in here,
                    datasets: [{
                        data: //what i have to put in here,
                        label: 'Infected',
                        borderColor: '#3333ff',
                        fill: true
                    }, {
                        data: //what i have to put in here,
                        label: 'Recovered',
                        borderColor: 'green',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                        fill: true
                    },{
                        data: //what i have to put in here,
                        label: 'Deaths',
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5)',
                        fill: true
                    }],
                }}
            /> ): null
    );
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data can be accessed using `this.state.data`, you need to refactor

```
const data = this.state
```

to

```
const {data} = this.state
```

Which is same as saying

```
const data = this.state.data
```

Comment: Welcome @ChuẩnPhạm. Happy to help. If this solved your problem then please mark the question  solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
Array.isArray(data) ?
data.map((data,index) => <div key={index}>{data.bind your data}</div>) :  error
}
```

think this should help.

Comment: In user's code data is referring to state, which is not an array therefore data.length will throw error. For array check, it is recommended to use ```Array.isArray``` .

Comment: @gautamits yeah got it now actually res.data can be given directly to the array in setState right.?

Comment: Yes
```
this.setState({data: res.data});
```
is perfectly fine. Please update your code so that OP does not get confused.

Comment: @gautamits Yeah done,i have posted a question based on pagination(state updation)can you plzz take look at that,which would help.

Comment: Sure. Please provide link.

Comment: @gautamits  thankyou.!  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501415/how-to-update-state-of-class-component-from-functional-component

Comment: @Arvind Udayashankar Thanks for your answer but i'm new to ReactJs and not sure what you mean when you said "{data.bind your data}". What can i do here to solve my problem? Just a bit more clearer please! Thanks!!!!

Comment: @chaun Pham data.specify the array or object in which the data is present  for example if have users[name,age] data.name,data.age like that.